# How to set default timezone in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to set default Timezone offset (America/Chicago) in date field. new Date function added into the code and call it properly into HTML file. its showing date and time properly but i want to set time zone default to  America/chicago.
code in controller :

```js
<script>
    mainApp.controller('depositController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) { 
          $scope.myDate = new Date(); 
    }]);  
</script>
```

html code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <input id="deposit_date" name="deposit_date" 
        class="form-control"       
        type="text" 
        ng-init="deposit_time=(myDate | date:'HH:mm:ss a' : '-0500')" 
        ng-model="deposit_time" 
        readonly="readonly"/>
</div>
```

I want to show America/Chicago (Central Standard Time) current time.

Comment: You mean the timezone should *always* be America/Chicago, and never adapt to the user?

Comment: @mistalis Yes , timezone should be America/Chicago always.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. AngularJS uses browsers timezone settings.

Look at the documentation:

> **[Timezones](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)**
>   - The AngularJS datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the browser.
>   - The same application will show different time information depending on the time zone settings of the computer that the application is running on.
>   - Neither JavaScript nor AngularJS currently supports displaying the date with a timezone specified by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's depends on the browser settings

> - The AngularJS datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the browser.
> - **The same application will show different time information depending on the time zone settings of the computer that the application is running on**.
> - Neither JavaScript nor AngularJS currently supports displaying the date with a timezone specified by the developer